# If statements printing error

Tags: python

So I have this program where it to prints all the users data that's been entered and gives the corresponding messages according to what they have entered:

```
nameslist = []
hourslist = []
morestudents = True


while morestudents:
    name = raw_input("Enter name : ")
    nameslist.append(name)
    hours = int(input("enter hours booked : "))
    hourslist.append(hours)
    more = raw_input("add more students? (yes/no): ")
    if more <> "Y" and more <> "y" and more <> "yes" and more <> "Yes":
        morestudents = False
    print

for x in range (len(nameslist)):
    print
    print nameslist[x],"You have", hourslist[x], "hours in total"
    print
    if hourslist >=10 and hourslist <= 14:
        print "You have 1 free hour"
    elif hourslist >= 15:
        print "You have 2 free hours"
    elif hourslist <= 9:
        print "You have no free hours"
```

nameslist is an array of all the names entered and hours is an integer that the user enters. Anyways when I have more than one person enter their hours then even when their hours is greater than 10 it always print "You have no free hours". This problem does not occur when there is only one person. I have tried so many methods to try to fix this but nothing works, Thanks.

Here is the what i get:

```
Enter name : Jack Smith
enter hours booked : 21
add more students? (yes/no): y
Enter name : John Wayne
enter hours booked : 2
add more students? (yes/no): n

Jack Smith You have 23 hours in total

You have no free hours

John Wayne You have 2 hours in total

You have no free hours
```

Comment: You aren't using hourslist...

Comment: The code in question does not match the output! `hourslist` will be empty which causes `IndexError: list index out of range`.

Comment: sorry i forgot this part hourslist.append(hours)

Comment: Same thing happens when i change hours to hourslist, i had tried it before:

Comment: Now you are using the hourslist array goofy: `if hourslist >=10 and hourslist <= 14:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One key problem that you have in the code is that you dont use the hourslist.

Between line 9 and line 10 you should add hourslist.append(hours)

and in the **if statement** You didnt add the index of hourslist

```
nameslist = []
hourslist = []
morestudents = True


while morestudents:
    name = raw_input("Enter name : ")
    nameslist.append(name)
    hours = int(input("enter hours booked : "))
    hourslist.append(hours)
    more = raw_input("add more students? (yes/no): ")
    if more <> "Y" and more <> "y" and more <> "yes" and more <> "Yes":
        morestudents = False
    print

for x in range (len(nameslist)):
    print
    print nameslist[x],"You have", hourslist[x], "hours in total"
    print
    if hourslist[x] >=10 and hourslist[x] <= 14:
        print "You have 1 free hour"
    elif hourslist >= 15:
        print "You have 2 free hours"
    elif hourslist <= 9:
        print "You have no free hours"
```

Comment: yeah I forgot to add that part, but even with it i have the same errors

Answer (score 0):

You don't update **hours** in for loop, so **hours** will be your last input number.

Comment: like this? `hours = hourslist[x]`

Comment: Or simply use hourslist[x] in your "ifs" like `if hourslist[x] >=10 ...`